# How to reconnect a screen session every time terminal is fired?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, awk

I wrote this command to reconnect an active screen session when Terminator is opened. It works find but there has got to be a better way to to it

This is goes in the Terminator config file (note myhost is my computer name)

```
r=$(screen -ls | awk '{print $1}' |grep myhost); screen -r $r
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, definitely over-complicating things:

```
screen -R
```

Where:

`-R          -- reattach if possible, otherwise start a new session`